# Merge 2 empy cells in to at the bottom of my table

Tags: vba, excel

I am looking to make a simple macro that will merge two of the empty cells at the bottom of my table (A4 and A5 for example). I know the following will identify the Rows:

```
LastRow = Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row + 1
NextEmptyRow = Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row + 2
```

But beyond this all i know is the following to select the entire column up to this point

```
Range("A1:A" & NextEmptyRow).select
Selection.Merge
```

I have tried the code bellow just to see if it would work, but it doesn't.

```
Range("A" & LastRow : "A" & NextEmptyRow).select
Selection.Merge
```

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should fix your problem:

```
Range("A" & LastRow & ":A" & NextEmptyRow).select
```

Comment: Thanks! Works beautifully! Had to +2 and +3 on my LastRow and NextEmptyRow to make it work but your fix was good.